# Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a cloud function  that listens to whether a new document is created in the `following` subcollection of some document of `users`. However, the user document upon previous creation may not have a `following` subcollection.

In other words, I want a cloud that responds to `db.collection(“users”).doc(“doc_id1”).collection(“following”).doc(“doc_id2”).set(new_document)`
, and I have written the cloud function to be

```
exports.create_friend_request_onCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{user_id}/{following}/{following_id}")
  .onCreate(f2);
```

And implementation of  `f2` is written in some other file

```
exports.f2 = async function(snapshot) {
 //some code
}
```

However upon creation the document in the subcollection, I get the following error

`Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.`

Can someone explain to me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 13):

I had a same problem and this reason of the problem is doc path must be a string.
`collection("questions").doc(21)` is wrong.
`collection("questions").doc("21")` is work.

-you have to make sure the variables are strings
.You can use `"users/{String(user_id)}/{following}/{String(following_id)}"`

Comment: thanks you saved my lots of time. just silly mistake to forgot to add String.

Answer (score 2):

The correct path should have been `'users/{user_id}/following/{following_id}'`, apparently the double quotes cannot be used as paths.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  .document("users/{user_id}/{following}/{following_id}")
```

into this:

```
  .document("users/{user_id}/following/{following_id}")
```

The `collection` shouldn't have a `{wildcard}`

Comment: I'm still getting the error after making the change and deploying

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them as string. Easiest way is format string.

Usage:
`${your_any_type_value}`

Caution: `undefined` or `null` will be show as "null" and "undefined".

```js
 exports.create_friend_request_onCreate = functions.firestore
  .document(`users/${user_id}/${following}/${following_id}`)
  .onCreate(f2);
```

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me because in my Controller (of the API) I had something like this.

```
export const deleteUserGallery = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { user_id } = req.params
```

You need to change your req.params to req.body if that's the case, to something like this:

```
export const deleteUserGallery = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const { user_id } = req.body
```